# How do you remove the throbber from drupal 7 Ajax link?

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

we are using drupal 7 ajax framework to load content on a page. When the link is clicked a throbber  shows up after the link while the request is processed.

I can't find documentation on how to set or remove the throbber. In a form it looks really simple, but using an ajax link and a callback menu item I can't find any documentation.

I see that there is a $settings variable that can be passed to the ajax_command_html function, but I don't see any docs as to how it should be formatted.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a "throbber" is? ;-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber

Answer (score 21, accepted):

when you build your form item you need to define the "progress" property:

```
$mycheckbox=array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => 'Load it up',
  '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_callback', 
      'wrapper' => 'checkboxes-div',
      'effect' => 'slide', 
      'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
    ),
);
```

You can find more information and examples [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example--ajax_example.module/group/ajax_examples/7)

Comment: There are tons of docs for how make these changes to elements handled by FAPI, but nearly nothing about how to handle a link.

Comment: True that, as mirzu mentioned, if you aren't using the FAPI, drupal_pre_render_link() is the best way to handle it, actually the FAPI calls drupal_pre_render_link() to construct links anyway so you're basically just skipping to the important layer, for anyone who isn't familiar, just format your link array like you would any other html element that you plan on letting drupal render, i.e.: `array('#href'=>'my_url','#title' => 'my link title', '#ajax'=>array('callback'=>'my_ajax_callback'));` etc.

Answer (score 10):

You may just hide the div.ajax-progress-throbber by set the display value to none:

```
.ajax-progress-throbber {
  display: none;
}
```

The module like CSS Injector (http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question. The important thing to understand is that there are 2 ways that links can be rendered in Drupal 7. The first is using the old [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7) function  and the other is using a render array. Many of the theme functions in Drupal use the old style and when it's used it is not run through the [drupal_prerender_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_pre_render_link/7). Which is what does the element pre-processing that communicates the settings from php to the js layer.